# Detect optional function argument (scalar)

Tags: awk, function, arguments

Consider this script:

```
function alfa(bravo, charlie) {
  if (charlie)
    return "charlie good"
  else {
    return "charlie bad"
  }
}
BEGIN {
  print alfa(1, 1)
  print alfa(1, 0)
  print alfa(1, "")
  print alfa(1)
}
```

Result:

```
charlie good
charlie bad
charlie bad
charlie bad
```

Does Awk have a way to tell when an argument has not been provided?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do this:

```
function alfa(bravo, charlie) {  
  if (charlie) {
    return "charlie good"
  }
  if (charlie == 0 && charlie == "") {
    return "charlie not provided"
  }
  if (!charlie && charlie != 0) {
    return "charlie null"
  }
  if (!charlie && charlie != "") {
    return "charlie 0"
  }
}
```

Result:

```
charlie good
charlie 0
charlie null
charlie not provided
```

Answer (score 6):

`awk` doesn't have a builtin way to check variable had been initialized. You must do it yourself:

```
function alfa(bravo, charlie) {
  if (charlie == 0 && !length(charlie))
    return "charlie bad"
  else {
    return "charlie good"
  }
}
BEGIN {
  print alfa(1, 1)
  print alfa(1, 0)
  print alfa(1, "")
  print alfa(1)
}
```

The general way:

```
var == 0 && !length(var)
```

An uninitialized variable and 0 causes `var == 0` to be evaluated to true, `!length(var)` excludes the case when `var = 0`.